# Specflow - getting specflow to generate vb.net code in the output window

Tags: vb.net, nunit, specflow

Hi does any one know how to configure specflow to output step definitions in a nunit output window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible currently. We will provide a Visual Studio editor feature soon where you can even generate bindings without running the tests.

Br,
Gaspar